# Why with elastic fabric, do crumbs fly away?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Currently lying down watching a wonderful kids film, eating oaty biscuits, and dropping lots of crumbs on myself.I intuitively understand if I pull my elastic t-shirt and suddenly release, the crumbs will fly away. As I imagine, the shirt should only travel towards my body as I release the potential energy and no force should be applied upwards for the crumbs to fly away. What is physically occuring.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you pull your shirt away from your body and then release the shirt. The shirt will move towards your body, then, when it hits your body, it will have kinetic energy, so it will (partially) rebound from your body and hit the crumbs in the direction away from your body.